# Double Website Host

Tags: html, web, host

I have a website that is critical to keep online 100% of the time.
I have a decent host, but every once in a while even the best host can go down.

It is for this reason that I was wondering if there was a way to have your website "double-hosted".

I'm using c-Panel, but I'm haven't found anything in there that could help.

I know it'll be some mess with having to change the nameservers as well, so is there an easy way to quickly switch up nameservers, in case my first host should go down?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Why not just run it via Cloudflare which displays an offline version if and when your website goes down for whatever reason?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use Wordpress, you can install another website on another Webhoster but use the same Database. Problem: Your ISP just can take one IP Adress for your website. When http://idontknow.com goes offline, the DNS Record have the IP from your http://idontknow.com server. Now you can change the IP adress when you see that your website goes down, but the changes can take up to 24 hours.

I think the best way is to use cliudflare. So you can redirect on your second page that use the same Database.

The struture is like this:

Server 1: Database
Server 2: Website 1 (Primary)
Server 3: Website 2 (Backup)

Now when cloudflare know that your server have no response it will be redirect to Server 3. When the Server is online again, it will be redirect to Server 2.

Greetz